# Validate a set of dropdown when a radio button is selected Jquery/PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have 6 radio buttons

XS | S | M | L | XL | XXL | XXXL | Custom

under custom radio button I have a couple of drop downs (select) boxes  like
Pant Waist | Pant Hip | Pant Front | Pant Back | Pant Inseam

under these drop downs are options like
Pant Waist
26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 ....

I want jQuery to validate if radio buttons are selected else error message and if custom button is selected then I need to validate if they have selected from all the dropdown (select) boxes if not then error message.

I am using this for woocommerce hence I have to target .single_add_to_cart_button click function

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).attr('id') == 'custom') {
          jQuery('.custom-sizes').show('slow');
        } else {
          jQuery('.custom-sizes').hide('slow');
        }
      });
    
    });
    
    jQuery('.single_add_to_cart_button').click(function() {
      if (jQuery('input[type="radio"]'.val() == 'custom').prop('checked'))
    
      {
        jQuery('.validate').each(function() {
          if (jQuery(this).val() == 'select') {
            jQuery('.customchecked-error').show();
            return false;
          } else {
            return true;
          }
    
        });
      }
    
    });
```

```css
  .sizes {
      margin: 20px auto;
    }
    
    .sizes input {
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
    
    .sizes input[type=radio] {
      display: none;
      margin: 15px !important;
      cursor: pointer !important;
    }
    
    .sizes input[type=radio] + label {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 4px 12px;
      background-color: #e7e7e7;
      border-color: #ddd;
      cursor: pointer !important;
    }
    
    .sizes input[type=radio]:checked + label {
      background-image: none;
      background-color: #000;
      color: #fff;
      transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
      cursor: pointer !important;
    }
    
    .custom-sizes {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .custom-sizes label {
      font-size: 12px !important;
      font-weight: 300 !important;
    }
    
    .custom-sizes .selections {
      margin-bottom: 20px !important;
    }
    
    .custom-sizes select {
      width: 100% !important;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


        <div class="sizes">
      <h4>Please Select a Size</h4>
      <input class="checkcase" type="radio" id="xs" name="standard_size" value="xs">
      <label for="xs">XS</label>
      <input class="checkcase" type="radio" id="s" name="standard_size" value="s">
      <label for="s">S</label>
      <input class="checkcase" type="radio" id="m" name="standard_size" value="m">
      <label for="m">M</label>
      <input class="checkcase" type="radio" id="l" name="standard_size" value="l">
      <label for="l">L</label>
      <input class="checkcase" type="radio" id="xl" name="standard_size" value="xl">
      <label for="xl">XL</label>
      <input class="checkcase" type="radio" id="xxl" name="standard_size" value="xxl">
      <label for="xxl">XXL</label>
      <input class="checkcase" type="radio" id="xxxl" name="standard_size" value="xxxl">
      <label for="xxxl">XXXL</label>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input class="checkcase" type="radio" id="custom" name="standard_size" value="custom">
      <label for="custom">Custom</label>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="custom-sizes">
      <p>Customize Your Look <a class="mpg-lightbox" href="/images/size-measure.jpg"><span> How to Measure</span></a></p>
      <div class="custom-size-options">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-3 selections">
            <label>Waist<span class="show_required"> *</span></label>
            <select class="pant_waist validate" name="pant_waist">
              <option value="select">Select</option>
              <option value="24">24</option>
              <option value="25">25</option>
              <option value="26">26</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 selections">
            <label>Hip<span class="show_required"> *</span></label>
            <select class="pant_hip validate" name="pant_hip">
              <option value="select">Select</option>
              <option value="30">30</option>
              <option value="31">31</option>
              <option value="32">32</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 selections">
            <label>Front<span class="show_required"> *</span></label>
            <select class="pant_front validate" name="pant_front">
              <option value="select">Select</option>
              <option value="30">30</option>
              <option value="31">31</option>
              <option value="32">32</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 selections">
            <label>Back<span class="show_required"> *</span></label>
            <select class="pant_back validate" name="pant_back">
              <option value="select">Select</option>
              <option value="30">30</option>
              <option value="31">31</option>
              <option value="32">32</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 selections">
            <label>Inseam<span class="show_required"> *</span></label>
            <select class="pant_inseam validate" name="pant_inseam">
              <option value="select">Select</option>
              <option value="30">30</option>
              <option value="31">31</option>
              <option value="32">32</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the fiddle link
https://jsfiddle.net/b5wrrj4h/

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
if (jQuery('input[type="radio"]'.val() == 'custom').prop('checked'))
```

Use the `ID` of the button like so:

```
if (jQuery('#custom').prop('checked'))
```

Here is a fiddle of it in action:

https://jsfiddle.net/u0u86ug6/

Edit:

In order to validate for the other checkboxes, add an `else` statement to your code like so:

```
if (jQuery('#custom').prop('checked')) {
...
} else {
  if (jQuery('.checkcase').prop('checked') == false) {
    jQuery('.customchecked-error').show();
  }
}
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hysxpjt8/

Comment: Thanks for a quick response but then it is not validating if noting is selected for example if I dont select anything and add it does not give an error.

Comment: It still gives me an error when i select a standard size other than custom it still gives me an error can we do something about it.